# Estimating the amount of objects given a single image

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, computer-vision, regression, yolo

I'm looking for a way of ESTIMATING the amount of lemons given an image like that below.

[image]

I was wondering me if this problem can be modeled as a REGRESSION problem and if so what would be a good alternative to achieve it. Note that I'm not looking for detecting each lemon, only estimate how many lemons is there.

For a first attemp, I tried to train a deep multilayer CNN using tensorflow with a single neuron in the last layer. Unfortunately, I got no great results.

Comment: look for "crowd counting". estimating the number of heads in a crowd is probably similar. do not expect exact results. these pictures do not have exact results. anything based on segmentation can struggle.

Comment: This paper should be of interest to you: ***Learning to Count Anything: Reference-less Class-agnostic Counting with Weak Supervision***, arXiv 2022.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pretrained MaskRCNN model and compute the number of distinct masks generated, where each mask corresponds to a lemon.

Alternatively, you can also use a pretrained model based on FasterRCNN. It would generate the bounding box predictions for possible lemons, you would need to filter out overlapping bounding boxes using Non-maximum suppression.

Another approach would be to use a pretrained image segmentation model and train one with lemons. Additionally, in this case, since there is no one correct value but rather a range of values would be acceptable, I suggest adding a weighted loss, where the loss penalty would be much higher if the predictions were away from the ground truth than if they were closer.

E.g., if the actual number of lemons in the photo is 60 and your model predicts 55 which is in the range of acceptable error, penalize the prediction by applying a small penalty (say 0.5). Similarly, if the prediction is 40 which is far away from the actual prediction, apply a penalization of 5. This penalization forces the model to produce predictions in an acceptable range after which you can further fine-tune the model to improve predictions.

One more approach would be to divide the image into many different boxes of equal dimension with a fewer number of lemons and train a model that works well on these boxes. I believe that your model gets confused when the number of lemons is high, and it should learn and converge faster on smaller images.
Then you aggregate the results with some margin of error.